# Dot-notation for properties within Javascript constructors

Tags: javascript, constructor, properties

I'm working through a text book and a lesson introduces the use of dot notation when defining a constructor. (It is understood that there is other syntax to use to name a property.) When experimenting with permutations of the lesson, an outcome causes some confusion.

One outcome is expected, undefined, from the following example:

```
function person(){
  person.thing = 2;
}

console.log(person.thing);
// outcome: undefined
```

However, an alternative experiment with first creating an object from the constructor produces an unexpected outcome for the value of `person.thing`:

```
function person(){
  person.thing = 2;
}

var bob = new person();

console.log(bob.thing);
// outcome: undefined

console.log(person.thing);
// outcome: 2
```

Why is the value for the property `person.thing` now 2 after a differently named object, `bob`, was created from the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

`person` always refers to that function object. When you call the `person` function, it actually runs so it places that property on the object.

This is no different the function putting a property on any other object, like this:

```js
var myObj = {}
function person() {
   myObj.thing = 2
}

console.log("person.thing:", person.thing) // undefined
console.log("myObj.thing:", myObj.thing)   // undefined

var bob = new person()

console.log("bob.thing:", bob.thing)       // undefined
console.log("person.thing:", person.thing) // undefined
console.log("myObj.thing:", myObj.thing)   // 2
```

So the only difference is that we're now adding the `thing` property to the `myObj` object instead of the `person` function object.

So `person` never has any relationship to the object being created by the constructor function... it *is* the constructor function.

---

Within the constructor function, the way to access the object being created is by using the `this` keyword. So if you did `this.thing = 2`, then `bob.thing` would be `2`.

Comment: Can I ask a follow up here?

Comment: Yep, what's up?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using *person*

```
function person(){
  person.thing = 2;
}

var bob = new person();

console.log(bob.thing);
// outcome: undefined

console.log(person.thing);
// outcome: 2
```

change it to **this**

```
function person(){
  this.thing = 2;
}

var bob = new person();
console.log(bob.thing);
// outcome: 2

console.log(person.thing);
// outcome: undefined
```

> did you notice the OUTCOME?